# calling the same function with different variables - simplifying the code

Tags: javascript

```
function removeIcons(x) {
  x.forEach(function (element) {
  element.remove()
  })
}

removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".film-icon"))
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".music-icon"))
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".book-icon"))
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".software-icon"))
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".smile-icon"))
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".article-icon"))
```

How can I write it simplier? I mean, the name of the function shouldn't repeat.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Just select all elements with a single selector? `removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".film-icon,.music-icon,.book-icon,..."))`

Comment: You could also incorporate the querySelectorAll into your function: `if(typeof x==='string') x = document.querySelectorAll(x);`. That way you can call it with a string or `NodeList`

Comment: If only those icons use class names ending on `-icon`, you can have a more concise selector for all icons: `'[class$="-icon"]'`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'm very grateful for your help. fjc, I had no idea how to go about it. I couldn't find anything on Google. Felix Kling and Mamun - that seems to me the best solution. David784 - very interesting, I'll keep that in mind. Connexo - I'll use that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target all the elements at once by specify the classes separated by comma using [**Document.querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(".film-icon, .music-icon, .book-icon, .software-icon, .smile-icon, .article-icon"));
```

Comment: It's either `Document.prototype.querySelectorAll` or `document.querySelectorAll`. `querySelectorAll` is **not a static method**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to do your task as

```
var iconlist = [".film-icon", ".music-icon", ".book-icon", ".software-icon", ".smile-icon", ".article-icon"];
iconlist.map(item => removeIcons(document.querySelectorAll(item));
```

Comment: I think forEach  is more appropriate. Map works, but it is generally used when you want to apply a function to every item and create a new list with them. Since we are not using the return value from returnIcons, forEach fits.

Comment: Hien Nguyen and Dejke. Thanks a lot for yur answers. I haven't got enough knowledge to comment on what you wrote. This arrow (=>) I have already seen on a course and at the beginning I suspected it would be part of the solution to my problem, but the solution proposed by Felix Kling and Mamun appeals most to me.